# Unable to compile SFML C++ code with g++ from Visual Studio Code

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-code, g++, sfml

I'm trying to compile some C++ code in Visual Studio Code but I want to use the SFML library and for some reason it just can't find my library. I am using the c/c++ extension which is configured like this

```
{
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Win32",
        "includePath": [
            "${workspaceFolder}/**", "C:\\lib\\SFML\\include\\**"
        ],
        "defines": [
            "_DEBUG",
            "UNICODE",
            "_UNICODE"
        ],
        "compilerPath": "C:\\TDM-GCC-64\\bin\\g++.exe",
        "cStandard": "c11",
        "cppStandard": "c++17",
        "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64"
    }
],
"version": 4}
```

and I've configured a task following [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38404670/how-do-i-link-the-sfml-libraries-in-visual-studio-code?newreg=0dc6c5435dd54b2cb5a0a641bb4e1a30) which gives me something like this

```
{
"version": "2.0.0",
"tasks": 
[
    {
        "label": "Compilation",
        "type": "shell",
        "group": "build",
        "command": "g++",
        "args": 
        [
            "main.cpp",
            "-o",
            "GUImeOfLife.exe",
            "-IC:C:\\lib\\SFML\\include\\SFML",
            "-LC:C:\\lib\\SFML\\lib",
            "-lsfml-graphics",
            "-lsfml-window",
            "-lsfml-system"
        ],
        "problemMatcher": "$gcc"
    }
],
"presentation": {
    "echo": true,
    "reveal": "always",
    "focus": false,
    "panel": "shared",
    "showReuseMessage": true,
    "clear": true
}}
```

However, when I run the task on my code (simply the example code from the SFML library website), I get this message from the compiler:

> Executing task: g++ main.cpp -o GUImeOfLife.exe -IC:C:\lib\SFML\include\SFML -LC:C:\lib\SFML\lib -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system
> main.cpp:1:24: fatal error: Graphics.hpp: No such file or directory
> compilation terminated.
> The terminal process terminated with exit code: 1

(The problematic line simply is `#include <Graphics.hpp>`)

What do I have to change to make it work?

Thanks

Comment: `"-IC:C:\\...`?

Comment: Yeah I don't actually know what it is supposed to do and how it works / searches for files so I eyeballed it but do you have something more precise/detailed to suggest ? I imagined it was meant to indicate where the lib and includes of the library where installed on my computer but if you could explain what I should put there instead I'd be happy

Comment: Instead of having `"C:C:\\"` have just `"C:\\"`?

Comment: But why ? If you happen to know how this works please give more details

Comment: Is e.g. `C:C:\\lib\\SFML\\include\\SFML` a valid path in Windows? Or is `C:\\lib\\SFML\\include\\SFML`? You have `C:` ***doubled*** (as `C:C:`) which makes the path wrong.

Comment: C:\\lib\\SFML\\include is a valid path. There was indeed no C:\\ in the original post (relative path) that I linked my post but I don't know how it works so I put the absolute path

Comment: Hi, I know this is a bit old, but I am struggling getting SMFL up and running with vscode? Did you have to build it with cmake or did you use one of the versions SFML provides - https://www.sfml-dev.org/download/sfml/2.5.1/ here?

Comment: I used the downloadable version from SFML. What is your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your configuration file

```
"-IC:C:\\lib\\SFML\\include\\SFML",
```

The path you present have an extra and wrong `C:` added in front.

The path should be

```
"-IC:\\lib\\SFML\\include\\SFML",
```

This ***typo*** is part of the `-L` option as well.