# How to link SFML libraries in Visual Studio Code in Linux?

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio-code, sfml

I am on Kali Linux, I am trying to use SFML libraries (C++) on Visual Studio Code.

To install SFML i used :

```
apt-get install libsfml-dev
```

From [How do i link the SFML libraries in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38404670/how-do-i-link-the-sfml-libraries-in-visual-studio-code) i tried for tasks.json :

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "g++",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "suppressTaskName": true,
    "tasks": [
        { 
            "taskName": "Compilation",
            "isBuildCommand": true,
            "args": ["-c", "${workspaceRoot}\\main.cpp", "-IC:\\SFML-2.4.0\\include"]
        },
        { 
            "taskName": "Liaison du fichier compilé aux bibliothèques SFML",
            "args": ["${workspaceRoot}\\main.o", "-o", "sfml-app.exe", "-LC:\\SFML-2.4.0\\lib", "-lsfml-graphics", "-lsfml-window", "-lsfml-system"]
        }
    ],
    "showOutput": "always"
}
```

I hace a couple of question : 
Is Tasks.json correct ? 
How to save Tsaks.json changes ? 
Do i have to put dll in the C++ project to make it work (and if i have to, where are the dlls) ?

I will be grateful, if someone can help me out in this problem. Cryptex

Comment: Kali? Putting DLL's in Linux code? There's too many red flags here. You're trying to run before you can even crawl.

Comment: Yes sorry, i forgot that there is no dll in linux. I deleted some flags.

Comment: Still - `C:\\SMFL-2.4.0\` on a Linux machine? I mean, the problem is deeper than just a tag. You seem to be missing a lot of necessary, elementary knowledge. And Kali is not at all suitable for complete beginners.

Comment: on Linux I would recommend using pkg-config. e.g. `pkg-config --libs sfml-all` this gives all the relevant flag you need. You can then incoporate that output in your json file.