# Error linking sqlite with C++ using vscode in windows

Tags: c++, sqlite, visual-studio-code

I'm doing a job that needs linking Sqlite with C++, but I've encountered some troubles doing this.

I've searched many courses already. I've added all the files more than needed
**sqlite3.dll,sqlite3.def,sqlite3.h.sqlite3.exe,sqlite3.lib**

into the project folder but I still failed to do it right.

[image]

[image]

the result of compiling main.cpp

[image]

## include "sqlite3.h"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Answer (score 1):

You just have to
1) add the .h header file to your include path
2) add the .lib library file to your libraries path
3) add a static link to the .lib file in your project properties (both debug and release builds)
4) remove all other references (def, dll, exe) from the project
5) make sure the .dll file is in the same directory as your .exe

Comment: How to take step 3 in detail?I have no idea.And for the step 5,which directory the .dll file and .exe file should be in?

Comment: I haven't used the Code edition of VS per se but the main principles should be pretty much the same to standard VS. However, looking around I found enough questions like this in the site that have not been answered.
For step 3 you can try entering the line
#pragma comment(lib, "sqlite3.lib")
after the includes section in your code of main.cpp.
For step 5 you should either add sqlite3.dll to a directory in your path or in the Debug and Release output directories of your project. You should also remember to deploy the .dll file together with your .exe.

Comment: You can also refer to the first answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38404670/how-do-i-link-the-sfml-libraries-in-visual-studio-code. You can try adding a "-lsqlite3", (including the comma after the quote) line in the end of your "args" section found inside the "tasks" section of your project's tasks.json file.

Comment: OK.I'll try it again.Thanks a lot.