# VS Code, C++, cant link external library, undefined reference

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, static-libraries

I have a problem and I can't fix it no matter what I do. Basically my university is using **Stanford libraries for c++** and the only program that can use those libraries out of the bag is **vs2008**.

I'd prefer to use VSCode, but I can't seem to get it to work. There is a folder with `.h` files and a compiled `.lib` file. The header files have nothing in them except for function names. Thing is that vs code can find those header files and recognizes functions but can't compile any of it. I guess it can't link to `.lib` file. How can I fix this? I did everything I knew but nothing worked.

Comment: What are you compiling with? If you check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38404670/how-do-i-link-the-sfml-libraries-in-visual-studio-code) then you can see how they have linked the SFML libs in vscode (with g++ as the compiler)

Comment: Hi Misho. Sounds to me like you don't fully understand how libraries work in C++. What you are looking at is a pre-compiled library, that provides headers with function definitions only. These headers cannot be compiled because, as you already noticed, they lack the function definitions. These headers are supposed to let your compiler know how the pre-compiled library can be used after linking. 

This means, your problem is about linking only, not about compiling the headers. As @NathanWride already wrote, please clarify how you run the compilation.

Comment: @Potaito, I did know what you said but my problem still stands. I'll tell you how my vsCode is setup.  I have following extensions in vsCode: c/c++, c++ IntelliSense, code Runner. I Also have a MinGW compiler on my system. all I do is write code in c++ and run it using (CTRL+Alt+N) shortcut. default libraries work as expected. now my uni situation: we have a folder that contains another folder with libraries (headers and compiled static library) and another folder that has CPP file(i have to fill that in). when I try to run this code I get "an undefined reference to" error.

Comment: I just do not know how to link those header files to a library they provided. 
P.S. we are using Stanford cs106b c++ library.

Comment: @MishoSaamashvili did you manage to link them?