# C++ multimedia library in vs code?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, sfml

I have recently been trying to download and install SFML to vs code but ever tutorial I've seen seems to be outdated and not working with the current verion of vs code. Is there a better alternative to SFML that works with the current version of vs code? Or, is there a more up to date tutorial that could help me install SFML?

Comment: My advice is to follow the official recommendation to install msys2 and use that to install MinGW and SFML directly from the builtin package management: [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw)

Comment: BTW to install sfml you search and find this page: [https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-x86_64-sfml?repo=mingw64](https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-x86_64-sfml?repo=mingw64) which gives you the exact line to paste into your mingw64 terminal to install: `pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-sfml` There are thousands of packages available with a similar 1 line install.

Comment: Once you get past using pacman to install you will have to edit your `tasks.json` to add the additional args for the compiler to link to the SFML libraries. pacman will install SFML in the system paths so you should not have to add any additional include path.

Comment: Thank you for you help, Im still rather new to all this so how do I go about editing my task.json to add args for my compiler to link to SFML?

Comment: [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw) explains the 3 files. But then to edit you have to understand how your compiler builds from the command line.

Comment: so under the args section i need to add a path to the sfml folder in task.json?

Comment: No that additional step (adding additional linker folders) is not needed if you installed using msys2 since msys2 will put the libraries in the standard system location. In the args section you need to tell your compiler to link to the individual sfml libraries.

Comment: See the args for this answer: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/65427207/487892](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65427207/487892) `"-lsfml-graphics",  "-lsfml-system",  "-lsfml-window"`